# Cannot read properties of undefined reading ("users") in schema for mongodb . this code was working the last few days

Tags: javascript, mongoose

connection api

---

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const MONGODB_URL = NEXT_MONGO_URL
 

if (!MONGODB_URL) {
  throw new Error(error);
}

let cached = global.mongoose;
if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = {
    conn: null,
    promise: null,
  };
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }
  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}
export default dbConnect;


user api
__________________________________________________________________________
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 256 },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 256 },
    username: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, "can't be blank"],
      match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
      index: true,
    },
    password: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 256 },
    age: { type: Number },
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, "can't be blank"],
      match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, "is invalid"],
      index: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamp: true }
);

const Users = mongoose.models.users || mongoose.model("users", userSchema);

export default Users;
```

I tried deleting and recreating the user part of the db and even rewriting the schema.

I currently have the same code working for my blog posts part of the db, so I don't think its the connection api

any help would be appreciated, please explain it like you would to a 10 year old
Ive been learning to code for a few month. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try and understand what the error message is saying: you're trying to access a property `users` on something that's undefined.

So that suggests that `mongoose.models` is undefined, because that's where you're trying to access that `users` property.

Since `mongoose.models` isn't even documented, I would suggest not using it and just use documented methods of retrieving a model:

```
const Users = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !! Basically I was trying to fix it in the wrong area. Ill look for the error on a page or api that uses the db.

Comment: In next js if i don't use structure like, const Review = mongoose.models.Review || mongoose.model("Review", reviewSchema), then it will give me error like Review model is already registered.

Comment: @KetanRathod [If you call `mongoose.model()` with twice the same name but a different schema, you will get an `OverwriteModelError`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.model())